# Add result of several calculations to total & store in variable

Tags: apex, trigger, forecast

Maybe I'm approaching this in completely the wrong way but..

In a trigger, I need to calculate an amount multiplied by a % which has been multiplied by an integer. For example if the amount is 100 and the percentage is 25% then in loop 1, the integer is 1 and the result is 25, in loop 2 the integer is 2 and the result is 50 etc.

Each time the calculation produces an amount, I want to add that amount to a total and store that total in a variable. **But I can't work out how to keep adding each amount that's calculated to the total?**

I'll then subtract that total from another amount and use that figure in additional calculations. The amounts that are being calculated are populating the Monthly_Settlement1__c field.

I'm doing the calculations in a loop so I can't use an SOQL query to SUM the amount from each record which has been created as part of the process.

For context, this is a calculation that spreads an annual revenue figure over a set number of months, taking into account a ramp up period when the revenue is reduced by a percentage and increases by equal increments.

Here's my code, the percentage is stored as Decimal 'Increment'

```
trigger MRFv2 on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    List<WEID__c> weids = WEID__c.getall().values();
    Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

    // add Opportunity Record Type Ids from Custom Setting to list of valid Ids      
    for(WEID__c weid: weids) {
        try {
            validRecordTypeIds.add(weid.WEOppId__c);
        } catch (System.StringException e) {
            System.debug(
                System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                'Invalid Record Type Id ' + weid.WEOppId__c
            );
        }
    }

    List<Opportunity> insOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> upOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Integer> rampDuration = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    Map<Id,Integer> forecastDuration = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    Map<Integer,String> monthName = new Map<Integer,String>{1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December'};
    List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c> newMRFs = new List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c>();
    List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c> existMRFs = new List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c>();

    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New){

        if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId))
        {
            try{
                Opportunity oldO = Trigger.OldMap.get(o.Id);

                if(oldO.CloseDate != o.CloseDate
                    ||
                    oldO.Implementation_Revenue__c != o.Implementation_Revenue__c
                    ||
                    oldO.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c != o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c
                    ||
                    oldO.FSR_End_Date__c != o.FSR_End_Date__c)
                {
                    upOpps.add(o);
                    rampDuration.put(o.Id , o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c));
                    forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));
                }
                //if old.Map is null, record has been inserted & MRF records should be added
            }catch(system.NullPointerException e){
                insOpps.add(o);
                rampDuration.put(o.Id , o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c));
                forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Implementation_Revenue__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));
            }
        }
    }

    if(insOpps.size() > 0){

    //deleted section

    }
    if(upOpps.size() > 0){

        for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id,
                            (SELECT Id FROM Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r) FROM Opportunity
                              WHERE Id IN :upOpps])
        {               
            system.debug('o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r size is ' + o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r.size());
            if(o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r.size()> 0){
                existMRFs.addAll(o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r);
                delete existMRFs;
            }
        }

        for(Opportunity o : upOpps){

            Date ic = o.Implementation_Revenue__c;
            Integer icm = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.month();

            //Ramp calculations
            Decimal increment = o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c;
            Integer rdur = (1 / increment).setscale(0, roundingMode.DOWN);
            //assume that if MRF duration is capped then so is the Annual Settlement figure
            Decimal monthlySett = o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c / forecastDuration.get(o.Id);

            //FSR calculations
            Integer fsrDur = forecastDuration.get(o.Id) - rdur;

            //add Monthly Forecast records for 'ramp' months
            for(Integer m = 0; m < icm + rDur + 1; m++){

                Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                fm.Name = monthName.get(ic.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ ic.addMonths(m).year();
                fm.Revenue_Date__c = ic.addMonths(m + 1).toStartOfMonth() - 1;
                //fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = (monthlySett*(increment*m + 1));
                //if test for empty list?
                newMRFs.add(fm);
            }

            //Decimal rampSett = ;
            //Decimal remSett = ;

            for(Integer m = icm + rDur; m < icm + fsrDur + 1; m++){

            }
        }        
    }
    insert newMRFS;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explicit question i.e. what do you want help with?

Comment: @KeithC apologies, I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a trigger, I need to calculate an amount multiplied by a % which has been multiplied by an integer. For example if the amount is 100 and the percentage is 25% then in loop 1, the integer is 1 and the result is 25, in loop 2 the integer is 2 and the result is 50 etc.
>
> Each time the calculation produces an amount, I want to add that amount to a total and store that total in a variable. But I can't work out how to keep adding each amount that's calculated to the total?

If I understand your question correctly, here's one possible solution to it.

```
list<decimal>dec = new list<decimal>();
Decimal d = 0.00;
list<integer>int = new list<integer>();
Decimal pct = .25;
Decimal LoopTotal = 0.00;
integer i = 0;
Map<integer,decimal>MonthMap = new map<integer,decimal>();

For(decimal d1:dec){
   
   d = d1*pct*int[i];

   LoopTotal = LoopTotal + d;

   MonthMap.put(i,LoopTotal);

   i++;

}
```

Note: If your list of integers is for months, you can easily populate that for record 0 to be 1 (Jan) and record 11 to be 12 (Dec) to cover your 12 month range. Putting this in a map allows you to retrieve it for each separate month throughout the 12 month period. You could also vary the percentage by using a list in a similar fashion for that value too.

> I'll then subtract that total from another amount and use that figure in additional calculations. The amounts that are being calculated are populating the Monthly_Settlement1__c field.

The above is why I've put everything in a map since I don't know when or where you'll need it. That part wasn't at all clear to me, but the above should be adaptable to most any situation I can think of.

Comment: Thanks, is Decimal d the amount 100 which I mentioned in my question?

Comment: `d1` is the amount 100, or first value in the list `dec` for that iteration. `d` is the amount that was calculated for that "iteration" (or month?) per my understanding of your question. `LoopTotal` is the sum of al values calculated for `d`, which increases with each iteration through the loop.

Comment: Ok, I'm 90% sure that this is what I need but it's going to take me a while to translate your answer back into my process. I will get back to you once I have though! Thanks again.